# Pass deserialized json data to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi How Do I pass deserialized json data to View. I tried the below but is not working.
I have a model class called **RootObject** and my action method class named GetAPIStringAsync()

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}


     [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> GetAPIStringAsync()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string APIdatas = null;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                APIdatas = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }


            var stringJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(APIdatas);


            //Only for Testing
            foreach (var item in stringJson)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Url);
            }



            Console.ReadKey();

            return View(RootObject);

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please change return type from string to ActionResult and try. like below

public async Task<**ActionResult**> GetAPIStringAsync()

ActionResult is the base class for all return types. go to

https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-different-types-of-action-results-in-mvc/    for more info

Comment: Thanks for adding the tuto link, I also wanted to ask you that.